Is it possible to differentiate devices connected to the same router in nginx logs?
We have a web server running nginx and a Rails app. Our logs have this format:
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

However, I would like to be able to differentiate if two requests with the same IP come from different devices or the same one.
I suspect one person is connecting from the same device using two different users in two different browsers, and therefore, different user agents and different session cookies.
Is there any way to log a device ip or identifier?

If you have some session bindings, you can have that, like, don't allow to establish second session while first one is running. Otherwise, there is always way to avoid such detection.

I don't understand what you mean, how would I avoid them creating a new session if I cannot detect if they already have one running in that device? @NikitaKipriyanov

What is the business problem behind this? Why do you have such a strange need?

Just a user I suspect is "farming points" by logging using two different profiles

Not in general.

Is there any way to log a device ip

You are already logging it – that's $remote_addr, and normally this would be the client device's IP address.
But if the router has NAT enabled, i.e. configured to overwrite the device's address within the packets with the router's own address, then that's all you get. After NAT, the original source address is no longer present in the packets and therefore not visible to your server in any way.
(IP was not designed with NAT in mind – the way it was designed is that the device's original address would remain unaltered all the way through – so when routers deliberately overwrite it, there's no "backup" field that would carry the original address anywhere.)
The NAT equipment itself still knows what the original address was, so if it's a router under your control, it could be queried for its mapping table (NAT state table) provided that you also log $remote_port, but if you don't have control over the router, then you have no way of knowing whether it hides one device or two or more.

or identifier?

The only such identifier across an IP-based network is the IP address itself.

We're talking here not just about TCP but HTTP, so in principle there can be a tag in the cookie header, that can be set differently on different devices, but that is very easy to circumvent (e.g. by using different browser profiles on a single device, to appear as different browsers), which is exactly what is happening.

I mean, yes, but OP already addressed HTTP cookies in their question before asking for an identifier.

thanks for answering! is NAT usually enabled? is it something that's common or default in routers nowadays?

and cookies would not work, as @NikitaKipriyanov said, I think they are using different browsers in the same device (I know they use firefox for one user and chrome for the other)

Depends on what kind of router. Home/small office wifi routers? Almost guaranteed to be enabled. Larger enterprise routers, on the other hand? Very rare. (More generally, NAT is something you'd do on the outer boundary of the whole network – where you meet your ISP – but not internally within a network. So if you have e.g. a large corporate or university network that consists of many routers, those should never do NAT between themselves (as there is no need for it), unless of course someone bought an off-the-shelf home wifi router and didn't configure it properly.)
